# Increasing graphics memory using RAM on Toshiba laptop?

Tags: integrated-graphics

I was wondering if you could give me some guidance. I've just got a Toshiba Satellite 5280 l855-s5280p Laptop, Intel i5, 8Gb RAM and Intel HD Graphics 400. I would like to increase my graphics memory (which is currently 64 mb) by using 1GB of RAM. I'm new at this and I haven't found any tutorial or video explaining how to do this. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having some specific issue that you expect this to fix? This sounds a lot like an XY problem -- you have some problem you expect this to fix, but the problem is actually something else.

Comment: well, actually I tried to play PES I couldn't even install it, according to the error that PES gave me, it was due low graphics memory...

Comment: It should be supported. What was the exact error message you got?

Comment: Hello again. It is a graphic issue. I tried to install Office, and I get the following error: Your graphic card does not fulfill the necessary requirements: (GPU:VRAM 128MB). Help please!

Comment: A google search for "Your graphic card does not fulfill the necessary requirements" (with either "graphic" or "graphics") revealed essentially no hits. Are you sure that's the exact error message?

Comment: Firstly install latest HD graphics drivers available for your laptop

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you need to do. It adjusts automatically.

And you really want the amount of graphics memory to be as little as possible -- the more memory the graphics subsystem uses, the slower it goes because memory accesses are the major bottleneck in shared memory graphics systems. Using more memory improves image quality, but performance takes a massive nosedive. It's a tradeoff, it's not a "more is better" thing.

Update: PES versions 2009-2012 had a bug that caused them to generate an error with shared memory graphics solutions. A patch is available for 2012.

> "As I said above, Pro Evolution Soccer 2011 (PES) has a bug where it incorrectly looks at dedicated vram versus total available graphics memory.  If the platform has BIOS option to bump up the dedicated vram, you can workaround this application bug.  If not, then you are stuck - you should contact Konami and ask them to patch the game.  If they are unwilling, then I recommend you let them know you will be choosing to play games from their competition in the future (FIFA 2011, Football Manager 2011)." - [Here](http://communities.intel.com/thread/24824?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what about Office? The error reads that my graphic card does not have the necessary requirements (GPU:VRAM 128MB)...

Comment: We need the *exact* error message. (And you should punch it into a search engine first because 9 times out of 10, you'll get your answer immediately that way.)

Comment: I know, I'm sorry, I posted it like that because my system is in Spanish. It literally says:  "Tu ordenador no cumple con los requerimientos minimos para ejecutar este programa, podrian producirse errores. Tu tarjeta grafica no cumple las especificaciones necesarias (GPU:VRAM 128MB)"

Answer (score 1):

Some BIOS on some laptops enables you to change the amount of memory allocated to video. Have a look through all the bios for anything that mentions video/vga set to 64mb and see if you can change it to 128 or 256. This will result in less ram for the computer.